# Google Conversion Tracking for OpenCart

Tags: variables, opencart, tracking

I have a serious problem here with the Conversion tracking code of Google. I've searched everywhere to no avail. I need to run this script on my Success page of OpenCart version 1.5.1.3.

```
<!-- Google Code for Sales Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 994251914;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "ifQwCN7LqQQQiqmM2gM";
var google_conversion_value = Total_Cost_Variable <--HERE IS THE PROBLEM
/* ]]> */
```

The problem is that I can't find the variable that shows the Total Cost of the purchased items in the Success page.
Please, any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that is readily available. You will need to extract the total cost from the order in the `checkout/success.php` controller file, then add it to the data to be passed to the view. This is because the success controller clears the cart before the success page, making the values non existent from that point forwards

Comment: yeah that's what i thought, any idea on how to do this? I'm not really familiar with that controller system of opencart and i see there're people that have the same problem unsolved in the opencart forums..

Comment: ok i've found a solution to my problem! For those interested: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=36214

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904) for general usage of controllers in opencart